# Always getting 0 rules when querying products/(id)/rules/count and 204 status from /rules

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm contacting the API of my client's store on BigCommerce.  I've verified the option set has a bunch of rules associated with it (8 product rules).

When I contact the api with 
     /api/v2/products/181/rules  I get a 204 response.
This seems to be an incorrect response.

I tried then contacting

```
 /api/v2/products/181/rules/count
```

and I get a response of:

```
{ count:0 }
```

How do I get a proper representation of these rules, as the API specification describes?

Thanks for any help you can provide.  I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The response indicates that there are no rules associated with the product ID in your request. Are you sure that the option set you're referring to has been assigned to the product ID referenced in your request? It is possible that the option set has rules but the product does not have an option set assigned to it.

Comment: Yes, I have discovered I can only obtain product rules, but not option set rules.  If an option set has rules, I can't see them from the REST API.  If I make them product rules, they are visible.